# how to copy three table data into one access c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, c#-3.0

I want one master table that keep track of all information for that I want to copy 3 data of 3 different tables of same database. I have **table1 ,table2 , table3 and want to copy in one table Master_table using C# 3.5.** So please help .

Answer (score 0):

If tables have same structure then you can directly merge them

```
dtAll = dtOne.Copy();
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);
dtAll.Merge(dtthree);
```

Else, if you have different structure for all three table then you can add them to dataset.

```
DataSet dsAll = new DataSet();
dsAll.Tables.Add(dtOne);
dsAll.Tables.Add(dtTwo);
dsAll.Tables.Add(dtthree);
```